# Anomalies in Google analytics datas

Tags: google-analytics

I detected anomalies in Google Analytics statistics for the year 2021 on a site I manage. The number of page views per session is in free fall, while the bounce rate and time spent per page is exploding (please, see the Google Analytics Datas link below).

I'm not sure if it's the current statics that are wrong, or the ones that were between February and October, or both, but there is definitely something wrong, and I don't know why.
Do you have any theories please?

[Google Analytics Datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcKZO.jpg)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you change some setting in GA (i.e. filter) or in GTM configuration?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.   Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, this question is specific to your site, so it would not be on-topic there either.

Comment: @MichelePisani I don't think so. Maybe a update from the plugin Lara's Google Analytics, or Google Site Kit, but I don't have an updates historic.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller In fact Google Analytics is a script loaded in Javascript. JS is often at the origin of wrong datas in GA. It just I don't know what happened right now.